# Roblox studio How do I change a TextLabel text in script

Tags: roblox

I want to make a gui that show your coordinates in game with text labels but my script seems didn't change the text at all

```
players = game.Players.LocalPlayer
players.CharacterAdded:Wait()
X = math.floor(players.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Position.X)
Y = math.floor(players.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Position.Y)
Z = math.floor(players.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Position.Z)
text = script.Parent.Text
while true do
    text = X..","..Y..","..Z
    X = math.floor(players.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Position.X)
    Y = math.floor(players.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Position.Y)
    Z = math.floor(players.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Position.Z)
end
```

please help me

I wanted to change the text to XYZ position in string
but everytime i launch the game the text didnt change
and it still at default text in roblox ui text label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## So I can see that you have made few mistakes here

### Explanation:

- First of all, `players.CharacterAdded:Wait()` doesn't always work and never works in studio. So instead of that, you should use `players.Character:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")`.
- Second thing. By calling `text = script.Parent.Text` you were requesting the text inside of it (you were getting it as a string), so to simply fix that you have to use `text = script.Parent` and then when changing text you will have to use `text.Text = "your text"`.
- The next one is making your while loop infinite by using bool true. You can't make it like that or else the playar may experience lag or even script may crash. So I'd suggest to put this to something like wait(0.1).
- And the last thing is that you should get X,Y,Z before putting it into the text or else it will be delayed.

---

### And your final script should be looking like this:

```lua
players = game.Players.LocalPlayer
players.Character:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")
X = math.floor(players.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Position.X)
Y = math.floor(players.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Position.Y)
Z = math.floor(players.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Position.Z)
text = script.Parent
while wait(0.1) do
    X = math.floor(players.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Position.X)
    Y = math.floor(players.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Position.Y)
    Z = math.floor(players.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Position.Z)
    text.Text = X..","..Y..","..Z
end
```

---

###### Keep scripting, nothing is easy without practice,

###### KubaDC

Comment: This LocalScript is already in the PlayerGui, there are no guarantees that the player's Character model exists at the moment this code executes. That means that it's possible that the line `players.Character:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")` will throw an `attempt to index nil with WaitForChild` error. A decent safety check is `if not player.Character then player.CharacterAdded:Wait() end` at the top.

Comment: That works thx and that was simple to know where is my problem i think i will mark you best answer

Comment: Make sure to add safety check made by Kylaaa

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to your question of how do I change a TextLabel text is you just [set the Text property](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/TextLabel#Text).

```
script.Parent.Text = "Hello World"
```

If you want a simple way to track the changing position of a player's character, I would recommend using the [Changed signal](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Instance#Changed) on the Part. It will fire the connected function every time the property changes, and it allows you to avoid using an infinite while-loop.

```lua
local text = script.Parent
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

-- wait for the player's character to exist
if not player.Character then
    player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
end

-- listen for changes to the player's position
local hrp = player.Character.HumanoidRootPart
hrp:GetPropertyChangedSignal("Position"):Connect(function()
    local position = hrp.Position
    local x, y, z = math.floor(position.X), math.floor(position.Y), math.floor(position.Z)

    -- format the position, and display it in the TextLabel
    local positionString = string.format("(%d, %d, %d)", x, y, z)
    text.Text = positionString
end)
```

Comment: It's work too but i can't get it how it work so easily i guess